# VB.NET How to obtain previous record entered from datatable?

Tags: mysql, wpf, database, vb.net, datatable

I would like to obtain the last record entered in my database and display it in a textbox.

Here is what I tried

```
Previous_Project_Float_Detail.Text = projectRecordDT.Rows(projectRecordDT.Rows("FloatNo").Count - 1).ToString()
```

`projectRecordDT` is my datatable populated with records using `mySqlDataAdapter`.

In my database, I would like to retrieve the last record of the column `FloatNo`.
Usually I am able to retrieve this by creating a new datarow. But how do I obtain it efficiently without having to loop the records every time by using datarows?

Comment: Are you talking about just getting the last row inserted?

Comment: Getting the last column record from the datatable. @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my own question because I misplace a parenthesis with the column name.

The correct way is

```
Previous_Project_Float_Detail.Text = projectRecordDT.Rows(projectRecordDT.Rows.Count - 1)("FloatNo").ToString()
```

The column name is after the row count. Not inside.
Also, this only works if the order of the records is already correct in your database.